# Explanation for a complicated regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have some text data as follows.

```
{"Timestamp": "Tue Apr 07 00:32:29 EDT 2015",Title: Indian Herald: India's Latest News, Business, Sport, Weather, Travel, Technology, Entertainment, Politics, Finance <br><br>Product: Gecko<br>CPUs: 8<br>Language: en-GB"}
```

From the below text, I am extracting title only (`Indian Herald: India's Latest News, Business, Sport, Weather, Travel, Technology, Entertainment, Politics, Finance`) using the following regular expression:

```
appcodename = re.search(r'Title: ((?:(?!<br>).)+)', message).group(1)
```

I am trying to understand how the above regular expression works.

`(?!<br>)` is a negative lookahead for `<br>`

`(?:(?!<br>).)+)` - what does this mean? Can someone break it down for me.
Also, how many capture groups are there in the regular expression.

Comment: This isn't complicated. You obviously haven't seen [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: @rr - Just started wrapping my head around regular expression.Will probably get to that in a couple of years :)

Comment: @liv2hak: :) Keep up your experiments, mind that everyone who is answering here also study it more and more every day.

Comment: Pick a regular expression visualizer/debugger, either a local GUI app or an online one like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/); it'll make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: This looks like a broken JSON. You should probably ask the site owner to fix the data.

Comment: @nhahtdh - I deliberately removed some sensitive data from JSON  :)

Comment: @liv2hak: Is it really broken in the first place?

Comment: @nhahtdh - No I broke it :)

Comment: @liv2hak: "Don't trouble trouble till trouble troubles you. It only doubles trouble and troubles others, too." :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need such a complicated regex to get the title. Use

```
Title:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<br/?>)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV2eD2/1)

We match `Title:`, then whitespace `\s*`, then any characters up tp `<br/>` with `(.*?)(?=\s*<br/?>)`.

As for `(?:(?!<br>).)+`, it means *capture 1 or more characters not followed with `<br>`*. There is an [SO post where this construction is explained in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word).

Here is an image from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kV2eD2/2) (go to *Regex Debugger* tab, then click `+` on the right) with the visualization what that construction is doing (checks if the next character is `<br>`, and if not, consumes and backtracks, etc):

[image]

As for the question regarding *how many capture groups are there in the regular expression*, `Title: ((?:(?!<br>).)+)` has 1 capturing (`((?:(?!<br>).)+)`) and 1 non-capturing (`(?:(?!<br>).)`) groups.

Comment: thanks :) But I am trying to learn.so I would like to know why my regex works as well :)

Comment: I added the explanation.

Comment: Also, please check the link I added.

Comment: You can also check the visualization of what `(?:(?!<br>).)+` is doing.

Comment: @liv2hak: `.` in `(?:(?!<br>).)+` does not refer to anything, it tells the regex engine to match any character but a newline. However, before matching ("consuming") that character, the regex engine checks if that character is `<`, and if yes, if the next is `b`, and if yes, checks if the next is `r`... and if it finds `<br>`, the `.` pattern does not trigger, the character is not consumed. If it is not found, the character is consumed, the engine goes on matching the substring in our input.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need lookahead here. What you're doing can be done using this simple regex also:

```
>>> re.search(r'Title: *(.+?) *<br>', message).group(1)
"Indian Herald: India's Latest News, Business, Sport, Weather, Travel, Technology, Entertainment, Politics, Finance"
```

btw your regex:

```
Title: ((?:(?!<br>).)+)
```

is using a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!<br>)` which checks presence of `<br>` before matching character after literal text `Title:`.

Comment: if it is after each character why is '.' coming after the negative look ahead?

Comment: Yes my bad, it is checking for presence of `<br>` **before** matching a character.

Answer (score 1):

What `((?:(?!<br>).)+)` means is:

```
((?:(?!<br>).)+)
^... Match the regex and capture its match into backreference 1

((?:(?!<br>).)+)
 ^... Match the regex (non capturing group)

((?:(?!<br>).)+)
    ^... Assert that it is not possible to match the regex <br>

((?:(?!<br>).)+)
            ^... Match a single character, that is not a line break character 

((?:(?!<br>).)+)
              ^... Between one and unlimmited times
```

Comment: capture its match into backreference 1 - means it is capturing group 1?

Comment: @liv2hak yes,  backreference 1 = capturing group 1

Comment: The non-capturing group applies only to <br> or also to `.` ?

Comment: The non capturing group applies also to `.`  --> `(?:(?!<br>).)`

Comment: So the `.` here refers to the characters following <br> and not to the characters before the `<br>` but after `Title`